# Оптимизация кода. Оптимизация обновления экрана. Игра в Жизнь Python. PyGame. Как оптимизировать алгоритмы в коде?

Tags: python, алгоритм, gui, оптимизация, pygame

Я пытался оптимизировать код различными способами, на одном из сайтов вычитал про двойную буферизацию экрана, но особого результата не заметил. Я осознаю что проблема именно в алгоритмах, которые я использую (функция get_next_generation, get_neigbours). Возможно стоит обновлять экран только при изменении клетки, но я не понимаю как это реализовать(функция update и pg.display.update). Так вот вопрос, как нужно переписать функции, в каком месте стоит обновлять экран для получения наибольшей производительности?

```
import pygame as pg
import pygame.time
import random

#Константы основного алгоритма
rules = {'born': [3], 'survive': [2, 3]}
cell_size = 20

#Экран
size = w, h = 1600, 800
flags = pg.FULLSCREEN | pg.DOUBLEBUF
screen = pg.display.set_mode(size, flags, 24)
pg.display.set_caption('Cell Machine')

#Цвета
black = pg.Color(0, 0, 0)
white = pg.Color(255, 255, 255)
dead = pg.Color(224, 255, 255)
alive = pg.Color(0, 139, 139)

#Шрифт
font = 'monospace'
font_size = 50


# Класс клеточки
class Cell:
    def __init__(self, x: int, y: int, life: bool = False) -> None:
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.rect = x, y, cell_size, cell_size
        self.life = life

    # Использовал этот метод для обработки нажатия ЛКМ
    def is_pressed(self, pos) -> bool:
        x, y = pos
        if self.x < x < self.x + cell_size and self.y < y < self.y + cell_size:
            return True

    def change(self) -> None:   #Меняет статус жизни клетки жива/мертва
        self.life = not self.life

    def render(self) -> None:   #Рисуем клетки
        if self.life:
            pg.draw.rect(screen, alive, self.rect)
        else:
            pg.draw.rect(screen, dead, self.rect)

    def clear(self):    # Метод убивающий клетку
        self.life = 0


class Buttons:  #Класс кнопки
    def __init__(self, x, y, background_color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.color = background_color

    def create_panel(self, width, height):  #Создание заднего фона для кнопки
        panel = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        panel.set_alpha(128)
        panel.fill(black)
        return panel

    def set_title(self, title):    #Получаем надпись которая будет на кнопке
        my_font = pygame.font.SysFont(font, font_size)
        text_surface = my_font.render(title, True, white)
        return text_surface


    def render(self, title_or_panel):   # Добавляем на экран полученную кнопку
        screen.blit(title_or_panel, (self.x, self.y))




# Функция подсчёта живых соседей НУЖНА ОПТИМИЗАЦИЯ
def get_neighbours(tar: Cell, cells: list) -> int:
    count = 0
    for cell in cells:
        if cell.life:
            x_sym = abs(tar.x - cell.x)
            y_sym = abs(tar.y - cell.y)
            # Горизонтальное, вертикальное или диагональное соседство
            h_nei = x_sym == cell_size and tar.y == cell.y and cell.life
            v_nei = y_sym == cell_size and tar.x == cell.x and cell.life
            d_nei = x_sym == cell_size and y_sym == cell_size and cell.life
            if h_nei or v_nei or d_nei:
                count += 1
        else:
            continue
    return count


# Просто рендер живых клеток
def update(cells: list) -> None:
    for cell in cells:
        cell.render()


# Обновление игрового поля НУЖНА ОПТИМИЗАЦИЯ
def get_next_generation(cells: list) -> None:
    created = []
    deleted = []
    for cell in cells:      #Здесь перебор все клеток, не уверен что это эффективно
        neighbours = get_neighbours(cell, cells)
        if cell.life:
            if neighbours not in rules['survive']:
                created.append(cell)
        else:
            if neighbours in rules['born']:
                deleted.append(cell)
    for new_cell in created:    #Этот блок нужен для того чтобы изменения клеток не влияли для дальнейшего перебора
        new_cell.change()
    for old_cell in deleted:
        old_cell.change()


def get_cells():        #Получаем список всех клеток
    cells = []
    for x in range(0, w, cell_size):
        for y in range(0, h, cell_size):
            cells.append(Cell(x, y))
    return cells


def randomize_cells(cells):     #рандомное заполнение игрового поля
    for cell in cells:
        chance = random.choices(['0', '1'], weights=[50, 10])
        if chance == ['1']:
            cell.change()


def delete_all(cells):  # Делаем все клетки мертвыми
    for cell in cells:
        cell.clear()


# Главная функция
def main() -> None:
    pg.init()
    pygame.font.init()
    # Создание отображения состояние pause play
    button = Buttons(0, 0, black)
    panel = button.create_panel(1600, 60)
    pause_title = button.set_title('Pause')
    play_title = button.set_title('Play')

    cells = get_cells()
    pause = True
    running = 1
    pg.event.set_allowed([pg.QUIT, pg.KEYDOWN, pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN])
    while running:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                running = 0
            # По нажанию на ЛКМ клетка должна менять своё состояние
            # Живая / мёртвая
            if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                for cell in cells:
                    if cell.is_pressed(pg.mouse.get_pos()):
                        cell.change()

            if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_ESCAPE:    #Закрываем игровое окно
                    running = 0
                if event.key == pg.K_SPACE:     #Пауза по пробелу
                    pause = not pause
                if event.key == pg.K_r:         #Рандомное заполнение по R
                    randomize_cells(cells)
                if event.key == pg.K_d:         #Очищаем поле по D
                    delete_all(cells)

        # Попытка реализоваться паузу
        if pause:
            update(cells)
            button.render(panel)
            button.render(pause_title)
        else:
            get_next_generation(cells)
            update(cells)
            button.render(panel)
            button.render(play_title)
        pg.display.update()

    pg.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Мне кажется вам всё-таки нужно отказаться от модели "каждая клетка - независимый объект" и перейти к модели "есть поле N x N с несколькими состояниями ячеек". Да, клетки-объекты - это прикольно, но у вас получается сложность обработки О(N**2), и непонятно, как её можно сократить. А у модели с полем алгоритмическая сложность будет O(N), что для больших N будет сильно отличаться.

Comment: Разве что совместить обе модели и держать клетки не в списке, а в матрице... Но тогда клеткам не нужны свои координаты.

Comment: заменил класс клеточек на класс поля, все работает в разы быстрее. Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Ну, я так понимаю суть вы поняли, а то я не пояснил - что для поля достаточно будет проверить соседей каждой клетки, которых мы для поля сразу знаем - это небольшой квадратик вокруг клетки поля, теперь не нужно перебирать все остальные клетки вообще, чтобы найти этих соседей.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение проблемы с оптимизацией следующее: заменить класс клетки на класс игрового поля.

```
import pygame as pg
import numpy as np
import pygame.time

# Константы основного алгоритма
cell_size = 15

# Экран
size = w, h = 1600, 800
flags = pg.FULLSCREEN | pg.DOUBLEBUF
screen = pg.display.set_mode(size, flags, 24)
pg.display.set_caption('Cell Machine')

# Цвета
black = pg.Color(0, 0, 0)
white = pg.Color(255, 255, 255)
dead = pg.Color(224, 255, 255)
alive = pg.Color(0, 139, 139)

# Шрифт
font = 'monospace'
font_size = 50


class GameOfLife:
    def __init__(self):
        self.surface = screen
        self.width = w
        self.height = h
        self.scale = cell_size
        self.alive = alive
        self.dead = dead
        self.columns = int(h / cell_size)
        self.rows = int(w / cell_size)
        self.grid = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(self.rows, self.columns), dtype=bool)

    def run(self):
        # Обновляем и рендерим поле
        self.draw_grid()
        self.update_grid()

    def draw_grid(self):
        # Рисуем клетку
        for row in range(self.rows):
            for col in range(self.columns):
                if self.grid[row, col]:  # Если статус 1 - рисуем живую
                    pygame.draw.rect(self.surface, self.alive,
                                     [row * self.scale, col * self.scale, self.scale,
                                      self.scale])
                else:  # Если статус 0 - рисуем мертвую
                    pygame.draw.rect(self.surface, self.dead,
                                     [row * self.scale, col * self.scale, self.scale,
                                      self.scale])

    def update_cell(self, x, y):
        # Получаем следующее поколение клеток(поля)
        current_state = self.grid[x, y]
        alive_neighbors = 0

        # Get to how many alive neighbors
        for i in range(-1, 2):
            for j in range(-1, 2):
                try:
                    if i == 0 and j == 0:
                        continue
                    elif self.grid[x + i, y + j]:
                        alive_neighbors += 1
                except:
                    continue

        # Updating the cell's state
        if current_state and alive_neighbors < 2:  # dies as if by underpopulation
            return False
        elif current_state and (alive_neighbors == 2 or alive_neighbors == 3):  # lives to the next generation
            return True
        elif current_state and alive_neighbors > 3:  # dies as if by overpopulation
            return False
        elif ~current_state and alive_neighbors == 3:  # becomes alive as if by reproduction
            return True
        else:
            return current_state

    def update_grid(self):
        # обновляем поле
        updated_grid = self.grid.copy()
        for row in range(updated_grid.shape[0]):  # shape() выводит колличество клеток  в строках/столбцах
            for col in range(updated_grid.shape[1]):
                updated_grid[row, col] = self.update_cell(row, col)

        self.grid = updated_grid


class Buttons:  # Класс кнопки
    def __init__(self, x, y, background_color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.color = background_color

    def create_panel(self, width, height):  # Создание заднего фона для кнопки
        panel = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        panel.set_alpha(128)
        panel.fill(black)
        return panel

    def set_title(self, title):  # Получаем надпись которая будет на кнопке
        my_font = pygame.font.SysFont(font, font_size)
        text_surface = my_font.render(title, True, white)
        return text_surface

    def render(self, title_or_panel):  # Добавляем на экран полученную кнопку
        screen.blit(title_or_panel, (self.x, self.y))


# Главная функция
def main() -> None:
    pg.init()
    pygame.font.init()
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    # Создание отображения состояние pause play
    button = Buttons(0, 0, black)
    panel = button.create_panel(1600, 60)
    pause_title = button.set_title('Pause')
    play_title = button.set_title('Play')

    game = GameOfLife()
    game.draw_grid()
    pg.display.update()
    pause = True
    running = True
    pg.event.set_allowed([pg.QUIT, pg.KEYDOWN, pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN])
    while running:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                running = False
            if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_ESCAPE:  # Закрытие игрового окна на esc
                    running = False
                if event.key == pg.K_SPACE:  # Пауза/отжатие паузы на пробел
                    pause = not pause

        if pause:
            button.render(panel)
            button.render(pause_title)
        else:
            game.run()
            button.render(panel)
            button.render(play_title)
        clock.tick(10)
        pg.display.update()

        # Попытка реализоваться паузу

    pg.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```